# Node.JS Javascript fetching file from directory returning same file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to read data files from a directory called 'myfiles' using a script 'app.js'.

The file to be read depends on the configurations passed to 'app.js' by another process which generates the files 'log.txt' and 'config.json'.

'app.js' then reads the files 'log.txt' and 'config.json' and fetches a data file from 'myfiles' based on the file name received.

The files in 'myfiles' are labeled `my-files1.txt, my-files2.txt, my-files3.txt, ... etc`.

The problem is, I keep fetching the same file 'my-files1.txt', even though 'log.txt' and 'config.json' provide new names for files to fetch.

Could you please help me spot where the problem is?

Thanks for your help!

app.js:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const { resolve } = require('path');

function readLog() {
    try { 
        return fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/' + 'log.txt',  'utf8');
    }   
    catch (err) { 
        return '';
    }       
}

function readConfig() {   
    try { 
        return fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/' + 'config.json',  'utf8');
    }
    catch (err) { 
        return '';
    }
}

let config = readConfig(); 
let log = readLog();
            
let cfg = JSON.parse(config);
let lcg = JSON.parse(log);

var currentPage = lcg.tPartition; // Current page to fetch
const numberOfPages = 10; 

if((cfg.running!=true) && (Number(currentPage)>Number(numberOfPages))){
    currentPage = 1;
}

function readDataset() {
    try { 
        return fs.readFileSync(resolve(`./app/assets/myfiles/my-files${currentPage}.txt`),  'utf8');
    }
    catch (err) { 
        return err;
    }
}

let dataset = readDataset();

const data = {
    data1: dataset // set dataset as value of data1
}

module.exports={data};
```

Answer (score -1):

you have written

```
let lcg = JSON.parse(log);
```

but your log is a txt file how can you parse it,  is this the problem let me know if this worked by any chance;

Comment: 'log.txt' and 'config.json' are in the same folder, but not inside the '/myfiles'.

Comment: @Vakindu i have changed the answer

Comment: @Vakindu check if this can help u.

Comment: @Vakindu try changing utf to utf-8

Comment: same issue persist. Don't think it's an encoding problem. Maybe I'm calling the readfilesync wrong?

Comment: @Vakindu i have changed the answer see if it works